# What causes an induction cooker to lower heat level by itself

Tags: induction, appliances

It's more than 5 years old. It is difficult to cook in high temperature because the minus sensor appears to be activated all the time. I end up going from 1600 to 400 every time. What must be the reason for this?

Comment: what is a minus sensor?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely explanation is it detects overheating in the electronics module (not the pot) due to ventilation clogged by dust, so it shuts down. Opening the device and looking inside should answer that question.